# how to combine two publisher in one in spring reactor

Tags: project-reactor, spring-webflux

I have implemented a dummy reactive repository but I am struggling with the update method:

```
@Override
public Mono<User> updateUser(int id, Mono<User> updateMono) {
    return  //todo with getUser
}

@Override
public Mono<User> getUser(int id) {
    return Mono.justOrEmpty(this.users.get(id));
}
```

From one hand I have incoming publisher `Mono<User> updateMono`, from the other hand I have another publisher during `Mono.justOrEmpty(this.users.get(id))`.

How to combine it together, make update, and give back just one publisher?

The only thing come to my mind is:

```
@Override
public Mono<User> updateUser(int id, Mono<User> updateMono) {
    return  getUser(id).doOnNext(user -> {
        updateMono.subscribe(update -> {
            users.put(id, new User(id, update.getName(), update.getAge()));
            System.out.format("Updated user with id %d to %s%n", id, update);
        });
    });
}
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [the reference guide on finding the right operator](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/docs/index.html#which.values)

Notably, for `Mono` you have `and`, `when`, `then` (note this last one will become `flatMap` in 3.1.0, and flatmap will become `flatMapMany`)

`doOnNext` is more for side operations like logging or stats gathering. Subscribe inside subscribe is another bad form; generally you want `flatMap` or similar instead.

Comment: thanks a lot, i've seen this guide but missed what i need. works perfect!

Comment: @SergiiGetman, I think you should update your question then with the "complete" solution for future references...

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ i marked it as `answered` or you mean something else?

Comment: That's cool; what I meant was: if the solution (the code) that you have on the answer is the final one, leave it as it is...otherwise, edit it and include the updated one so people can refer to it later on for the same purpose. That's what I do...you don't have to if you think this is enough.

Answer (score 3):

I have played Spring 5 Reactive Streams features in these days, and have written down [some sample codes](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/)(not public via blog or twitter yet, I still need more practice on Reactor).

I have encountered the same problems and finally used a `Mono.zip` to update the existing item in MongoDB.

https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/boot-routes/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> update(ServerRequest req) {

    return Mono
        .zip(
            (data) -> {
                Post p = (Post) data[0];
                Post p2 = (Post) data[1];
                p.setTitle(p2.getTitle());
                p.setContent(p2.getContent());
                return p;
            },
            this.posts.findById(req.pathVariable("id")),
            req.bodyToMono(Post.class)
        )
        .cast(Post.class)
        .flatMap(post -> this.posts.save(post))
        .flatMap(post -> ServerResponse.noContent().build());

}
```

**Update**: Another working version written in Kotlin.

```
fun update(req: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
    return this.posts.findById(req.pathVariable("id"))
            .and(req.bodyToMono(Post::class.java))
            .map { it.t1.copy(title = it.t2.title, content = it.t2.content)    }
            .flatMap { this.posts.save(it) }
            .flatMap { noContent().build() }
}
```

Comment: i thought about `zip` at the very beginning. so i had two publishers and my task itself was transform one into another, and `flatMap` fits its requirements according documentation :
`Transform the item emitted by this first Mono asynchronously, returning the value emitted by another Mono (possibly changing the value type)`. 
`zip` could be useful in case of many monos: `Zip the values from given monos together using a combinator function`

Comment: @SergiiGetman I understand your meanings, originally I thought the two publishers should be fork/join relation in the flow and then combined into one Mono in the flow for further operations.